# (Java) Parsing JSON from file error

Tags: java, json

I have a file `query.json` that contains `[["Rain"], ["Cloudy", "Sprinkler"], [false, true]]` to represent a query for a Bayesian network.

`String queryContents = readEntireFile(new File("query.json"));`
`Query query = Query.queryFromString(queryContents);`

Is used to read the entire file and then call the method to create the query.

When I call my `queryFromString(String s)` method I get the error:

`Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING`

my `queryFromString` method is

```
    public static Query queryFromString(String s) { 
    Gson gson = new Gson();  
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray jsonNodes = parser.parse(s).getAsJsonArray();
    JsonElement element = jsonNodes.get(0);
    JsonArray jsonNode = element.getAsJsonArray();
    String [] q = gson.fromJson(jsonNode.get(0), String[].class);
    String [] e = gson.fromJson(jsonNode.get(1), String[].class);
    boolean[] v = gson.fromJson(jsonNode.get(2), boolean[].class);



    return null;
    }
```

This is my first time using JSON, so I' not really sure why it is producing this error, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root JSON value is a JSON array containing 3 other JSON values: two JSON arrays containing string values and a JSON array containing boolean values.

You should be operating on the root JSON array directly.

```
JsonArray jsonNodes = parser.parse(s).getAsJsonArray();
String[] q = gson.fromJson(jsonNodes.get(0), String[].class);
String[] e = gson.fromJson(jsonNodes.get(1), String[].class);
boolean[] v = gson.fromJson(jsonNodes.get(2), boolean[].class);
```

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you...Its the little things that get you sometimes.